# expo authSession keycloak config

Tags: react-native, expo, keycloak

i'm using react native with expo and i want to use keycloak  version 21 as openid connect provider, im reading the auth session configuration but it's not an provided a keycloak example,
the url for the connection that i use is: `https://iam.mydomain/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth`
Im trying to test this configuration:

```
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#identityserver-4
```

but always returning this error

```
Error: Cannot prompt to authenticate until the request has finished loading.


WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
const useProxy = true;
const redirect_uri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
  useProxy,
});

export default function Index() {
  // const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState(false);

  const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery(
    "https://iam.domain/realms/realm"
  );
  // Create and load an auth request
  const [request, result, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: "vue-id",
      redirectUri: redirect_uri,
      scopes: ['openid', 'email', 'offline_access', 'profile'],
    },
    discovery
  );
return (
<View>
 <Button title="INGRESAR" onPress={() => promptAsync({ useProxy })} />
        {result && <Text>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</Text>}
      </View>)
```

So please help me.
Greetings

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: I'm updating thanks for the reply